# ODEs: determining dependence of solution on force

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

I am pretty sure this problem has a quite simple solution, but it seems I cannot find it.

Assume I have the following one dimensional IVP:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}+f(x) = g(w,t) \\ x(0) = x_0 \\ \frac{dx}{dt}(0) = x_1
\end{equation}
where $x_0$ and $x_1$ are constants.

I would like to know how $x_w(w,t) \equiv\dfrac{\partial x }{\partial w}(w,t)$ evolves in time. (Assuming $x(w,t)$ is differentiable once in $w$).

Normally, I would say that computing:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2 x_w}{dt^2}+f_x(x) x_w = g_w(w,t) \\ x_w(0) = 0 \\ \frac{dx_w}{dt}(0) = 0
\end{equation}
will do the job. However, when I use the same technique for $\ddot{x}+x = \cos(wt)$ with arbitrary intial conditions, it does not seem to work (for $|w| \neq 1$):

\begin{equation}
\ddot{x} + x = \cos(wt) \\
x(0) = 1, \dot{x}(0) = 0.
\end{equation}
The solution to this is:
\begin{equation}
x(w,t) = \cos(t)+\dfrac{1}{1-w^2}(\cos(wt)-\cos(t)) \\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial w} = \frac{2w}{(1-w^2)^2}(\cos(wt)-\cos(t))+\frac{1}{(1-w^2)}(-t\sin(wt))
\end{equation}
This is the accurate solution. However, using:

\begin{equation}
\ddot{x}_w + x_w = -w\sin(wt) \\
x(0) = 0, \dot{x}(0) = 0
\end{equation}
gives:
\begin{equation}
x_w(w,t) = \dfrac{-w}{1-w^2}(\sin(wt)-\sin(t)) \\
\end{equation}
which is different than $\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}$.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made an algebra error:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\left[\cos(wt)\right] = -t\sin(wt)
$$
whereas you have $-w\sin(wt)$. Fix this and it all works.

Comment: My life, that was a stupid mistake. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From differentiating the d.e. with respect to $w$, 
$$  \dfrac{\partial^3 x_w}{\partial t^2\; \partial w} + f'(x_w(t)) \dfrac{\partial x_w}{\partial w} = \dfrac{\partial g_w}{\partial w} $$

So (assuming $x_0$ and $x_1$ don't depend on $w$) $p_w = \dfrac{\partial x_w}{\partial w}$ and $x_w$ satisfy the system

$$ \eqalign{\dfrac{d^2 x_w}{dt^2} + f(x_w) &= g_w\cr
            \dfrac{d^2 p_w}{dt^2} + f'(x_w) p_w &= \dfrac{\partial g_w}{\partial w}\cr
x_w(0) &= x_0\cr
\dfrac{d x_w}{dt}(0) &= x_1\cr
p_w(0) &= 0\cr
\dfrac{d p_w}{dt}(0) &= 0}$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have fixed the formulation (forgot to mention that: f'(x)). Besides my mistake, I dont think your formulation is different than mine. Nonetheless, this does not seem to work (I have added the particular case where it does not).